# Understanding software parallelization on a linux workstation

Tags: linux, multithreading, parallel-processing

**Summary**

I am trying to understand the limits of my compute resources when performing multiple simulations. My task is trivial in terms of parallelisation - I need to run a large number of simple *independent* simulations, i.e. each simulation program does not rely on another for information. Each simulation has roughly the same running time. For this purpose I have created an experiment that is detailed below.

**Details**

I have two shell scripts located in the same directory.

First script called `simple`:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Simple Script

echo "Running sleep with arg= $1 "
sleep 5s
echo "Finished sleeping with arg= $1"
```

Second script called `runall`:

```
#!/bin/bash

export PATH="$PATH:./"

# Fork off a new process for each program by running in background
# Run N processes at a time and wait until all of them have finished
# before executing the next batch. This is sub-optimal if the running 
# time of each process varies significantly.


# Note if the number of total processes is not divisible by the alloted pool something weird happens

echo "Executing runall script..."

for ARG in  $(seq 600); do
    simple $ARG &
    NPROC=$(($NPROC+1))
    if [ "$NPROC" -ge 300 ]; then
        wait
        echo "New batch"
        NPROC=0
    fi
done
```

Here are some specs on my computer (MAC OS X):

```
$ ulimit -u
709
$ sysctl hw.ncpu
hw.ncpu: 8
$ sysctl hw.physicalcpu
hw.physicalcpu: 4
```

From this I interpret that I have 709 processes at my disposal and 8 processor cores available.

However when I execute `$ ./runall` I eventually end up with:

```
...
Running sleep with arg= 253 
Running sleep with arg= 254 
Running sleep with arg= 255 
Running sleep with arg= 256 
Running sleep with arg= 257 
Running sleep with arg= 258 
./runall: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
Running sleep with arg= 259 
./simple: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
Running sleep with arg= 260 
$ Running sleep with arg= 261
Finished sleeping with arg= 5
Finished sleeping with arg= 7
Finished sleeping with arg= 4
Finished sleeping with arg= 8
Finished sleeping with arg= 3
...
```

SO:

**Question 1**
Does this mean that out of the 709 processes available, only 258 can be dedicated to my `runall` program, the rest remaining probably being used by other processes on my computer?

**Question 2**
I substituted the `simple` script with something else which does something more complicated than just sleep (it reads a file and processes the data in the file to create a graph) and now I start to notice some differences. With the help of using `$ time ./runall` I can get the total run time and whereas before when calling `simple` for up to the 258 processes I always got a run time of about 5s:

```
real    0m5.071s
user    0m0.184s
sys     0m0.263s
```

i.e, running many simulations in parallel gives the same runtime as a single simulation. However now that I am calling a more complex program instead of `simple` I get a longer total run time than the single simulation time (calling a single simulation takes 1.5s whereas 20 simulations in parallel takes about 8.5s). How do I explain this behavior?

**Question 3**
Im not sure how the number of processor cores is related to the parallel performance - Since I have 8 cores at my disposal I thought I would be able to run 8 programs in parallel at the same time it would take me to just run one. Im not sure about my reasoning on this...

Comment: From [ulimit](http://ss64.com/bash/ulimit.html) manpage: -u   The maximum number of _processes_ available to a single user.

Comment: Yes perhaps I shouldn't confuse thread with process - ill edit that to avoid confusion.

Comment: I think I wanted to draw your attention to the fact that as a single user, you can't be running more than 709 processes simultaneously on this computer with those ulimit settings. And yes, you are creating separate processes (`fork` call -- the only way to create processes on Unix).

Comment: Ok I understand - is my reasoning otherwise correct?

Comment: I would suggest installing GNU `parallel`, and then running e.g. `seq 600 | parallel -j8 -n1 ./simple`. That would be a whole lot, well, simpler...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have 8 cpu threads available, and your programs consume 100% of a single CPU, it does not make sense to run more than 8 programs at a time.

If your programs are multi-threaded, then you may want to have fewer than 8 processes running at a time. If your programs occasionally use less than 100% of a single CPU (perhaps if they're waiting for IO), then you may want to run more than 8 processes at a time.

Even if the process limit for your user is extremely high, other resources could be exhausted much sooner - for instance, RAM. If you launch 200 processes and they exhaust RAM, then the operating system will respond by satisfying requests for RAM by swapping out some other process's RAM to disk; and now the computer needlessly crawls to a halt because 200 processes are waiting on IO to get their memory back from disk, only to have it be written out again because some other process wants to run. This is called [thrashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_(computer_science)).

If your goal is to perform some batch computation, it does not make sense to load the computer any more than enough processes to keep all CPU cores at 100% utilization. Anything more is waste.

Edit - Clarification on terminology.

- A single computer can have more than one CPU socket.
- A single CPU can have more than one CPU core.
- A single CPU core can support simultaneous execution of more than one stream of instructions. [Hyperthreading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading) is an example of this.
- A stream of instructions is what we typically call a "thread", either in the context of the operating system, processes, or in the CPU.

So I could have a computer with 2 sockets, with each socket containing a 4-core CPU, where each of those CPUs supports hyperthreading and thus supports two threads per core.

Such a computer could execute 2 * 4 * 2 = 16 threads simultaneously.

A single process can have as many threads as it wants, until some resources is exhausted - raw RAM, internal operating system data structures, etc. Each process has at least one thread.

It's important to note that tricks like hyperthreading may not scale performance linearly. When you have unhyperthreaded CPU cores, those cores contain enough parts to be able to execute a single stream of instructions all by itself; aside from memory access, it doesn't share anything with the rest of the other cores, and so performance can scale linearly.

However, each core has a lot of parts - and during some types of computations, some of those parts are inactive while others are active. And during other types of computations could be the opposite. Doing a lot of floating-point math? Well, then the integer math unit in the core might be idle. Doing a lot of integer math? Well, then the floating-point math unit might be idle.

Hyperthreading seeks to increase perform, even if only a little bit, by exploiting these temporarily unused units within a core; while the floating point unit is busy, schedule something that can use the integer unit.

...

As far as the operating system is concerned when it comes to scheduling is how many threads across all processes are runnable. If I have one process with 3 runnable threads, a second process with one runnable thread, and a third process with 10 runnable threads, then the OS will want to run a total of 3 + 1 + 10 = 14 threads.

If there are more runnable program threads than there are CPU execution threads, then the operating system will run as many as it can, and the others will sit there doing nothing, waiting. Meanwhile, those programs and those threads may have allocated a bunch of memory.

Lets say I have a computer with 128 GB of RAM and CPU resources such that the hardware can execute a total of 16 threads at the same time. I have a program that uses 2 GB of memory to perform a simple simulation, and that program only creates one thread to perform its execution, and each program needs 100s of CPU time to finish. What would happen if I were to try to run 16 instances of that program at the same time?

Each program would allocate 2 GB * 16 = 32 GB of ram to hold its state, and then begin performing its calculations. Since each program creates a single thread, and there are 16 CPU execution threads available, every program can run on the CPU without competing for CPU time. The total time we'd need to wait for the whole batch to finish would be 100 s: 16 processes / 16 cpu execution threads * 100s.

Now what if I increase that to 32 programs running at the same time? Well, we'll allocate a total of 64GB of RAM, and at any one point in time, only 16 of them will be running. This is fine, nothing bad will happen because we've not exhausted RAM (and presumably any other resource), and the programs will all run efficiently and eventually finish. Runtime will be approximately twice as long at 200s.

Ok, now what happens if we try to run 128 programs at the same time? We'll run out of memory: 128 * 2 = 256 GB of ram, more than double what the hardware has. The operating system will respond by swapping memory to dis and reading it back in as needed, but it'll have to do this very frequently, and it'll have to wait for the disk.

If you had enough ram, this would run in 800s (128 / 16 * 100). Since you don't, it's very possible it could take an order of magnitude longer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it correct to refer to them as CPU *threads* rather than *cores*? Is it correct to think of it as each program which runs in the background as belonging to a CPU core and therefore if more than 8 are used then they start to compete for resources leading to the degradation in performance as you mention (assuming they each require 100% of the cpu)?

Comment: @Jack your CPU is hyperthreaded. It has 4 cores (physical cores) and 8 threads (logical cores). If you believe Intel's marketing about a 30% improvement, 8 CPU threads on 4 physical cores is roughly equivalent to having 5 physical cores. This very much depends on the individual program and the actual gain can be 0% or less.

Comment: @thatotherguy Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Another question: This thrashing you speak of is something I likely met when I ran very many of the complex program in parallel. My computer froze and I needed to restart. Im assuming this is thrashing. My question is why doesn't a modern computer safeguard against this? Surely there is an easy way to stop the program taking resources from those processes that are critical for the computer to run under normal conditions?

Comment: Thrashing is likely what occurred. Your computer wasn't stuck, it was just going very slowly; you could have eventually recovered if you waited long enough. When the working set (amount of RAM needed simultaneously) is larger than available RAM, the OS swaps data stored in RAM to disk; the only alternative is to refuse to allocate the memory, at which point your programs (and maybe many others) will begin to fail. The choice is either: work, but slowly; or don't work at all. OS designers usually choose work but slowly. That said, you can configure limits.

Answer (score 1):

Your questions are a little confusing. But here's an attempt to explain some of it:

> Question 1 Does this mean that out of the 709 processes available, only 258 can be dedicated to my runall program, the rest remaining probably being used by other processes on my computer?

As the [ulimit manpage](http://ss64.com/bash/ulimit.html) explains, `-u` tells you how many *processes* you can start as a user. As you know, every process on Unix has a `uid` (there are some nitty gritty details here like `euid`, `setuid` etc.) which refers to the user on the system that *owns* that process. What `-u` tells you is the number of processes you (since you are logged in and executing the `ulimit` command) can start and simultaneously run on the computer. Note that once a process with pid `p` exits, OS is free to recycle that number `p` for some other processes.

> Question 2

The answer to question 2 (which seems to be your main confusion) can only be given when we understand what the `time` command actually reports. Understanding the output of the `time` command needs some experimentation. For instance, when I run your experiment (on a comparable Mac) with 100 processes (i.e. `$(seq 100)`), I get:

```
./runall.sh  0.01s user 0.02s system 39% cpu 0.087 total
```

This means that only 39% of the available computing power was used resulting in `0.087s` of the *wall clock* time. **Roughly speaking**, the *wall clock time* multiplied by the CPU utilization gives the running time (user time that your code needs + system time that system calls need to execute). Your `simple` script is rather too simple. It does not cause the CPU's to do any work by making the `sleep` system call!

Compare this example with a more real-life example to find a [subset of a given set with given sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem). This (Java) program, on the same computer produces the following times:

```
java SubsetSum  38.25s user 1.09s system 510% cpu 7.702 total
```

This means that the total wall clock time in about 7.7 seconds, but all the available cores are stressed extremely highly to execute this program. On a 4-CPU (8 logical CPU), I get a 500% CPU utilization! (And you can see that wall clock time (`7.7`) multiplied by CPU utilization (`5.1`) i.e. `39.27` is roughly equal to total time (`38.25+1.09 = 39.34`))

> Question 3

Well, the way to parallelize your programs is by finding out parallelizable activity in solving the problem. You have 8 cores available and the OS will decide how to allocate them to the processes that ask for it. But what if a process goes into `BLOCKING` state (blocked on I/O)? Then, the OS will schedule this process out and schedule something else in. A simplistic view of this like "8 cores => 8 programs at the same time" is hardly true when you take into account the way the scheduling works.

Comment: Good answer - it will take some time to digest. However one thing I need clarification on- 510% CPU utilisation - how is that possible? Are we saying that due to hyper threading we have about 5.1 times the power of one physical core? Also the output of your `time` seems to be different than mine - mine looks like the one in my question and doesn't contain CPU percentage!

Comment: This is one thing that throws off many people -- utilization beyond 100%. The key thing to remember is that 100% refers to one core. The `time` cmd is bash-builtin in my case, maybe you are using `/usr/bin/time` which produces an output without CPU %age (do `whereis time`).

Comment: Cool! So is the 510% due to hyper threading in this case (since you only have 4 cores technically?)

Comment: Yes. There are other factors, but basically yes. When I run the same Java program on a nearby Linux box with a quad core CPU (no hyperthreading), I get: `java SubsetSum  37.77s user 1.25s system 276% cpu 14.127 total` which means I am not able to stress it beyond say 300%. (You can also see that it takes longer for this computer to run this program).

Comment: I accepted the other answer as the examples given cleared up my confusion, but your answer was very good as well. Thanks for your help!